# How to solve page not found in django

Tags: django, custom-error-pages

im having a problem with page not found.
[Page not found error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BClzh.png)

In that pic you can see there is only the admin page, but not the calc page im looking for.

Project name is sharedlibrary.

Here is the urls.py under sharedlibrary

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('calc/', include('calc.urls')),
]
```

here is the urls.py under folder called calc

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('home/', views.home)
]
```

here is the views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home(request):
    return HttpResponse("hello world")
```

i wanted to get a primitive hello world program.
instead the calc/home/ page isnt showing, like if i wouldnt write it.

i tried:
restarting visual studio
restarting the terminal
restarting my pc
changing this code in the urls.py from:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('calc/', include('calc.urls')),
]
```

to this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('calc/', views.home, name="home"),
]
```

Comment: I'm watching to see how quick you get an answer. I'm considering Django, but want to see how active the community is.

Comment: According to that page, the ONLY url you have defined is `admin/`.  It does not know about `calc/` at all.  Are you sure the posted code is accurate?  Perhaps you edited the urls.py file but forgot to save the changes, or forgot to redeploy the app?

Comment: @Paulb No need to wait -- just browse recent activity on the `django` tag.

Comment: @JohnGordon I'm new to coding and I thought it is saving automatically. But saving that file fixed my issue, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please add your app to settings.py files installed apps list. Also run the migration commmands if not done earlier.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).